# Is there any way to automate downloading apk and ios simulator expo eas build in github action

Tags: android, ios, continuous-integration, expo, github-actions

I want to do automated tests in maestro cloud in my react native expo app but i don't know how to start from getting the build link to downloading it as an artifact and uploading it to maestro
what i want is:

- build the expo app (i think there's `eas build --json` command but idk how can i catch and get the desired output)
- download the ios simulator and apk files
- publish them to maestro cloud

I saw some github repos that automates builds but not for the purpose of e2e tests but for publishing app releases. couldn't find what i really needed.